# How to exit flash video in browser by keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browser, adobe-flash

If I'm watching a video in Adobe Flasher Player, say on Youtube, the player steals all focus after I clicked on it. That is, all the regular keyboard shortcuts of my browser - like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> to open new tab - are blocked.

To get the browser back into focus I could of course click somewhere outside of Adobe Flasher Player - but how can I bring Adobe Flasher Player out of focus by means of keyboard only?

Comment: When I watch a flash video on Youtube I still can use ⌘ + t and other keyboard shortcuts (Firefox 33.1, OSX 10.9). Can you please give details of your configuration?

Comment: I'm not sure but I suspect ESC will work. TAB might also work. This might be browser dependend though.

Comment: I can also sometimes do stuff when playing the video but not after clicking directly on the player, for example to pause. Then neither tab or ESC works. I found this consistent everywhere I tried. My main setup is Linux (Debian Testing)/Firefox 32.2